# C++ decision tree storage

Tags: c++, decision-tree

I have a decision tree.
I feed this decision tree some input values.
The decision tree then returns a value.

The input values could be "number of children", "age in years", etc.
The decision tree could then return (for example) a certain value that would indiciate how many cars the family possesses or something like that.

This decision tree (if converted to an if-then statement) would look like this:

```
int i=0;

if (ownedHouses==0)
{
    if (numberOfChildren==4)
    {
        if (ageFather==39)
        {
            if (incomeFamily==40000)
            {
                if (carsAlreadyCrashed==1)
                {
                    i=3;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (carsAlreadyCrashed==2)
                    {
                        if (insurancePaysForCrashes==1)
                        {
                            i=5;
                        }
                      }
                      else
                      {
                            i=4;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        i=11;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                i=2;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            i=9;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        i=22;
    }
else
{
    i=8;
}
```

This is is just an example. In reality, the resulting if-then statement would be absolutely huge. Although I can parse the data and create such an if-then from it, I could not use such a big if-then-loop in my software.

I am therefore searching for a different way to integrate the decision tree into my software.

I have seen approaches where the decision tree data (in whatever form it is provided...) is parsed at runtime, and then classes with root, nodes and leaves are created from it.

For my purposes this is not fast enough.

Does anybody have any other idea?

Thank you for the help.

Edit: I have changed some of the values to real-life values to make the meaning more clear.

Comment: What exactly is a `if-then-loop`? And it would be much easier to suggest something, if you told us abit more about what your input and output is supposed to look like (one size fits all is rarel the best solution).

Comment: @Grizzly is "If-then-struct" a better description?

Comment: @Grizzly: Many people I talked to call everything that has curly braces and is not a method a loop. So it's `if-then-loop`, `switch-loop`, `try-catch-loop`, and so on. I don't know why, but you can tell them hundreds of times it's not a loop and they will continue to call it one.

Comment: @tmighty: No. It's a statement.

Comment: @tmighty: "For my purposes this is not fast enough." - How have you come to that conclusion?

Comment: Surely this is just a query over a dataset - SQLite?

Comment: @Nick That would not be fast enough. I need more speed.

Comment: @tmighty have you verified this? SQLite is lightening fast and can be in-memory if required.

Comment: @Axel Creating the classes at runtime takes 2 seconds. I tried all kinds of optimizations. They did not result in the desired speed gain. I would need a new approach, I think.

Comment: @Nick Yes, I tried that already. I love SQLite, but for this task it is too slow.

Comment: If all the standard solutions are too slow for you, have you tried to take code-generation into your mind? Save your Decision tree as a *.c file, filled with your if-then-else magic, and let the compiler do that for you. I dont think that there is a faster way than code generation, and i dont think there is a way with more headache!

Comment: I have not tried that yet. I googled for the maximum length of an if-then-statement but did not find anything.

Comment: @EGOrecords Why "more headaches"?

Comment: Creating 'classes' i.e. objects will surely not be your bottleneck. More likely it's the parsing of whatever format you're using to store it in the first place. What you would presumably need is building a tree in memory (using objects w/ pointers to each other) and then serialising it to disk, in such a way where it can be quickly loaded into memory. You should profile your code and see whether you're right - is it the parsing or is it the object allocation, cos the latter sounds unlikely.

Comment: @tmighty There is no "maximum length" in the standard, it is limited by your RAM, the filesize and the comilation time. I have compiled source files that had around 10MB. More headaches, because you have to make shure you create standard-compliant sources, and you will be messing around with generating code, instead of your real task. And on the other side: it is not (really) possible to make it adapdive or in any way dynamic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fastest realization i know is implemented in [ALGLIB](http://www.alglib.net/dataanalysis/decisionforest.php).
Decision tree is stored as array of doubles.

- Leaf node - two values {-1, data}.
- Non-Leaf node - three values {input_value_index, threshold, right_branch_offset}.

You can find implementation of this approach in `dforest.dfprocessinternal`